# Using the result of a custom MySQL function in a WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the result of a custom MySQL function in the WHERE IN clause of a query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM project p 
 WHERE p.category_id IN (getCategorys(1))
```

The result of the custom function is as follows:

```
SELECT getCategorys(1)

 1,2,3,4,5
```

Unfortunately, this does not give the same result as:

`SELECT * FROM project p WHERE p.category_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

The query using the custom function only returns results where category_id = 1

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the FIND_IN_SET() solution that @Uueerdo mentions, it'll always do a table-scan. It can't use an index.

The only way to make this work with index optimization is to fetch the string of category id's before you prepare the query. In other words, do two queries.

Something like this (but I haven't tested it):

```
SELECT getCategorys(1) INTO @tmp;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
  SELECT * 
  FROM project p 
  WHERE p.category_id IN (', @tmp, ')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This is technically a case of SQL injection, even though it's using content that you produce from your own function. Be sure you have complete control over what your `getCategorys()` function returns.

For example, can the function ever return an empty string? That would result in `IN ( )` which is a syntax error.

Comment: I was clearly over complicating things. Simply fetching the contents of the IN clause before hand is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The form the results from the custom function take is not obvious from the question; but `IN` takes lists or results, not strings. I am guessing the function returns a string.

It's not ideal from a performance perspective but [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) may be easier to use to produce the behavior you want.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET does indeed work:

```SELECT * FROM project AS p WHERE FIND_IN_SET(p.category_id, getCategorys(1))```

Your remark about performance did scare me a little. How would I return something similar to csv string that can actually be used by ```IN``` ?

Comment: @ViBoNaCci Bill provided the only alternative answer. There is no other way than these two suggestions within mysql.

Comment: @ViBoNaCci Bill covered the performance issue I should have elaborated on. Basically, almost any time you have to a use a function on data in a condition (user or even built-in like FIND_IN_SET), you eliminate the possibility of indexes helping your query to execute faster. Bill's answer is much better if your method of database access doesn't preclude dynamic sql like that; though in that case, running two queries client side to the same effect would still be superior.

Comment: Yeah, there are cases that can be indexed if you use [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html), but this is not one of those cases.